# How to match words using Regex match method

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling to match the string against with regular expression.

```
assing_data = "Operating System,Batch-I(08:00:AM-09:00:AM)";
var pattn = /Operating System,Batch-I(08:00:AM-09:00:AM),php Programming,Batch-I(10:00:PM-11:00:PM)/gi
var result = assing_data.match(pattn)
console.log(result)
```

Output:

> Operating System,Batch-I(08:00:AM-09:00:AM)

Comment: Its not working

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your strings are mis-assigned. The longer string should be the data and the shorter string should be the Regular Expression pattern. As it is, it will never match since the pattern string is longer.

See more on the syntax for the `String.prototype.match()` function here documentation and example here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

```js
const paragraph = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. It barked.';
const regex = /[A-Z]/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
```

Additionally, you'll need to escape the `()` parens since they are used to indicate capture groups. Here's an article on what characters need to be escaped in a regular expression:

https://riptutorial.com/regex/example/15848/what-characters-need-to-be-escaped-

Update your code so it looks like the following:

```js
assing_data = "Operating System,Batch-I(08:00:AM-09:00:AM),php Programming,enter code hereBatch-I(10:00:PM-11:00:PM)";
var pattn = /Operating System,Batch-I\(08:00:AM-09:00:AM\)/gi
var result = assing_data.match(pattn);
console.log(result);
```

Here's a working example:

https://regex101.com/r/slyeHc/1/

Answer (score 0):

```regex
/(Operating System,Batch-I\(08:00:AM-09:00:AM\))|(php Programming enter code hereBatch-I\(10:00:PM-11:00:PM\))/gi
```

you could play here: https://regex101.com/